# number of ways to obtain a pair

Tags: probability, poker

Here is my attempt to find number of hands in a 5 cards poker game that gives one pair:

$ \binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3} \cdot 13$ - 2pairs - full house
=1349088-123552-3744=1221792

But it is wrong. What did I do wrong? I know I have the right numbers for full house and two pairs. I dont need another solution for obtaining number of hands that holds one pair. I only need to get an explanation for why this approach to finding number of one pair is wrong.

My approach is to find any hand that has 1 pair and any other 3 cards and then subtract hands in that category that gives other poker combinations which should be full house and two pairs.

Comment: Can you explain your $\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3} \cdot 13$ - 2pairs - full house in a little more detail? What are you doing for this? In addition, is this a hand of 5 cards, or 2 cards in hand and 5 on board for a total of 7 cards like in holdem?

Comment: To echo the other commenter, where does your formula come from?  What does it mean?  We can't address the calculation if we can't follow your thinking.

Comment: Also you're looking for the number of ways to obtain a pair and not two pairs as it says in your first line? Surely you've forgotten to subtract three of a kind and four of a kind as well?

Comment: dont think so I constrained it to 48 cards when I selected the other cards so that should leave out three and four of a kind I think.

Comment: In the body of your question you say (repeatedly) that you are trying to count hands with two pairs, but in your approach you seem to be assuming that you know the answer to that and are instead trying to use it to count the hands with one pair.  Can you clarify?

Comment: opps typo I meant that I was trying to find all 1 pair hands. Sorry! I have corrected it.

Comment: You partially corrected it, but it still says "two pairs" in a couple of places.

Comment: Your first term is still confusing.  It multiply counts hands.  For example it counts hands with two pairs twice.

Comment: @dromastyx  There can't be a flush (as we have at least one pair).  Nor can there be three or four  of a kind, other than in the full house case.

Comment: Yes Shuri2060. That is my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your approach is:

Select a card value. Now, from the $4$ cards with that value in the deck, select $2$ of them to be in the hand. Next, any $3$ of the other $48$ cards in the deck can go in the hand.

Now since there are $13$ different values, multiply by $13$.

The hands which aren't pairs using this approach are 2 pair and full house, so subtract them off the final total.

Correct?

---

The problem seems to be that you're counting the hands with two pairs twice here.

Example: I select Ace. Now I have AA in hand. I select 553 as the other cards for the hand AA553.

But when I select 5, I can also select 55AA3 as a hand which is the same.

---

There aren't any further problems, so $1349088-2(123552)-3744=1098240$ is actually the correct answer.

Comment: And counting a pair and a triplet....

Comment: "Next, any 33 of the other 48 cards in the deck can go in the hand."  False.  You might pick another pair or a triplet.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, but 2 pair (which are counted twice) and full houses are subtracted off after, so this is fine.

Comment: yes the description of my approach is correct. Thanks I did get it.

Answer (score -2):

You've counted all the hands that have a pair in, and then subtracted the hands with two pairs or a full house. You haven't subtracted the four-of-a-kind or triplet hands which also contain a pair.

Comment: Thats not quite the problem here

Comment: This is not an answer and surely fits as a comment.